# How do I enable/disable my Ribbon Buttons in Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have an Outlook Add-in created with VSTO. Using the Ribbon Designer I have created a tab with three buttons on it.  (*Environment: Outlook 2010, .NET 4.0, VSTO latest runtime*)

When one of the buttons is pressed a modeless dialog is opened. As long as the user is working on this dialog I do not want him to be able to press the button again. So basically I want to gray out the button till the dialog is closed. How can I do this?

For whatever reason, in the button click handler, if I do `this.button1.enabled = false;` it is just not working. Am I missing something about the way ribbons work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-render the control using `IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl(controlID)` or `IRibbonUI.Invalidate()`. See MDSN on how to [dynamically update the Fluent UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers_Dynamically) for reference. This is done for performance reasons so that you can change all your Fluent UI settings and then re-render all control changes at once. However, if you are only changing one UI element (*as you indicate*) this can seem confusing and unnecessary.